VS Code-esque line numbers in HTML/CSS/JSS
I'm attempting to create a code editor and want to implement vertical line numbers similar to those found in VS Code. I tried looking for tutorials on YouTube but was unable to find any.
Example:


Is it correct that you mean line numbers under "number thing"?

I guess yeah if that's what you mean a vertical line number than yeha

I guess I should change writing of this than

Have you tried using flexbox with flex-direction: column;?

Hi, welcome to SO. Please [edit] the question to show your own efforts at solving this, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Also please see [ask].

No I have not but IDK if that will display the verticalnumber or not

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have no problem I have no code all I want to be able to do I have that number line appear just like in vscode adn I was asking how to do it
